# how to write R in command line? how to Load workspaces from the command line?

Tags: linux, r, bash, command-line

I have two questions, thanks for anyone who maybe stopped by my questions

1. how to write R in command line? 
   I know it is easy just input R and Linux can lead you to R. also in windows I also can go to the file where you put R and run the software. 
   But, is there any other way to write R in command line without any visual R software?I do Not mean vi a file in unix, I need another way.
   I need to know, because I may need to do this in a server without any software. If you think there is no such way, also let me know "there is no way".
2. how to Load workspaces from the command line
   In the same situation as the first question,without any visual R software. I meant, well, loading from e.g. a bash shell, not from within an interactive R session itself.

Thanks for anyone who stopped by my question! Thanks!

Comment: A server "without any software", but presumably with R installed? I don't know if I can believe this.

Comment: @user2859850 what do you mean with I need another way? What is the problem with using nano (or whatever text editor is your flavor) to make a .R file and run it using R --no-save (or --save or --vanilla) < file.R and if you want add an output file using >outfile an example would be to make a file `test.R` and then use `R --vanilla <test.R` --vanilla in this case combines multiple commands to allow you to 'just run' the code without any other thing. use `man R` in linux command line to get more info about the options.

Answer (score 0):

1.I don't know how but I would say there is a way to call R to work on just command line

2.With just `load("myfile.RData")` where you have saved previously the workspace (`save.image("my.file.RData")`)you can recover it, in this case it loads the file of the current working directory, to change that you can just add a `path=` to the folder, of course assuming you are in a working environment either in command line or any other visual R software.

Answer (score 0):

I will interpret your question as "Can I run R program without R being actually installed on the system?"

If that's correct, you can see following excerpt from R for Windows FAQ. I am not sure if same can be done with linux.

> 2.6 Can I run R from a CD or USB drive?
>
> Yes, with care. A basic R installation is relocatable, so you can burn
>   an image of the R installation on your hard disc or install directly
>   onto a removable storage device such as a flash-memory USB drive.
>
> Running R does need access to a writable temporary directory and to a
>   home directory, and in the last resort these are taken to be the
>   current directory. This should be no problem on a properly configured
>   version of Windows, but otherwise does mean that it may not be
>   possible to run R without creating a shortcut starting in a writable
>   folder.